# A holomorphic function sending integers (and only integers) to $\{0,1,2,3\}$

Tags: cv.complex-variables

Does there exist a function $f$, holomorphic on the whole complex plane $\mathbb{C}$, such that $f\left(\mathbb{Z}\right)=\{0,1,2,3\}$ and

$\forall z\in\mathbb{C}\ (f(z)\in\{0,1,2,3\}\Rightarrow z\in\mathbb{Z})$?

If yes, is it possible to have an explicit construction?

Note that, for example, $h(z)=\frac{1}{6} \left(9-8 \cos \left(\frac{\pi z}{3}\right)-\cos (\pi z)\right)$ is not a valid solution, since, in particular, certain roots of the equation $h(z)=0$ are not integers, but complex numbers.

Also note that this question is answered in positive regarding the function $g$ such that $g\left(\mathbb{Z}\right)=\{0,1,2\}$ and $\forall z\in\mathbb{C}\ (g(z)\in\{0,1,2\}\Rightarrow z\in\mathbb{Z})$. In this case, an example of such function is $g(z)=1-\cos \left(\frac{\pi z}{2}\right)$.

Note: This is a repost from https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4624439/a-holomorphic-function-sending-integers-and-only-integers-to-0-1-2-3.

Comment: Just to complete the picture downwards, you can get $\{0, 1\}$ with $z \mapsto \tfrac1 2(1 + \cos(\pi z))$ and $\{0\}$ with $z \mapsto e^{2\pi i z} - 1$.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Such a function does not exist. Assume first that $f$ is real on the real line. We use the theorem of Marchenko–Ostrovski that if $f$ is entire and all zeros and solutions of $f(z)=3$ are real, then $f$ belongs to the Laguerre–Pólya class (closure of polynomials with all zeros real).
This theorem also tells us how the graph of this function on the real line looks like: if
$a_k$ are zeros and $b_k$ are 3-points, then
their order on the real line is
$$\dotsb a_k\leq a_{k+1}<b_k\leq b_{k+1}< a_{k+2}\leq\dotsb$$
with some choice of enumeration, and there is one critical point in each interval $[a_k,a_{k+1}]$ and in $[b_k,b_{k+1}]$, and no other critical points. The sequences of zeros and $3$-points are infinite in both directions.

In particular,
if $f(n)=0$, and $f'(n)\geq 0$ then $f(n+k)=k, 0\leq k\leq 3$, $f(n+4)=3$, $f(n+4+k)=3-k,\; 0\leq k\leq 3$ and so on.

Now fix $n$ such that $f(n)=0$, and consider the function on the interval $[n,n+3]$. Since $f(n+k)=0$, $0\leq k\leq 3$, the function $g(x)=f(x)-x+n$ has $4$ zeros on the interval, therefore $g'$ has at least $3$ zeros, and  $g''=f''$ has at least $2$ zeros. This contradicts the fact that for functions of Laguarre–Pólya class, the zeros of $f^{(n)}$ and $f^{(n+1)}$ are interlacent: the adjacent zeros of $f'$ lie in $[n-1,n]$ and $[n+3,n+4]$,
and thus $f''$ can have at most one zero on $[n,n+3]$.

Reference for the Marchenko–Ostrovski theorem:

[Zbl 327.34021](https://zbmath.org/0327.34021)
Marchenko, V. A.; Ostrovskii, I. V.
[A characterization of the spectrum of Hill’s operator](https://www.mathnet.ru/php/archive.phtml?wshow=paper&jrnid=sm&paperid=3807&option_lang=rus). (Russian)
Mat. Sb., N. Ser. 97(139), 540-606 (1975).
([English translation](https://zbmath.org/0343.34016)).

Remark 1. Marchenko–Ostrovski theorem has an a priori assumption that $f$ maps the real line into itself. However this property follows from our assumption that $f$-preimage of $4$ points belongs to the real line, see, for example,

[Zbl 1172.30004](https://zbmath.org/1172.30004)
Bergweiler, Walter, Eremenko, Alexandre
[Meromorphic functions with linearly distributed values and Julia sets of rational functions](https://doi.org/10.1090/S0002-9939-08-09788-8).
Proc. Amer. Math. Soc. 137 (2009), no. 7, 2329–2333. [arXiv](https://arxiv.org/abs/0808.3800).

where it is proved that whenever all solutions of
$f(z)=a$ are real, for $4$ distinct values of $a$,
the function maps the real line to itself.

Remark 3. Analysis of the above proof shows that a slightly stronger result holds: If $f(\mathbf{Z})\subset\mathbf{Z}$ and $f^{-1}(\{0,1,2,3\})\subset\mathbf{Z}$ then $f(z)=z+b$,
where $b\in\mathbf{Z}$.

Comment: Your Remark 2 is also remarked in the original question.

Comment: [Re](https://mathoverflow.net/posts/comments/1147455), the Math. Mono. link is also not freely accessible, so, in case you want to delete it, I put it here: [Goldberg, Anatoly A.; Ostrovskii, Iossif V. Value distribution of meromorphic functions](https://doi.org/10.1090/mmono/236). [Re](https://mathoverflow.net/posts/comments/1147459), the original question has [the trivial edit history](https://mathoverflow.net/posts/444411/revisions), but I couldn't swear it wasn't edited in the 5-minute window.

Comment: @LSpice: sorry, I had a wrong reference for the main result that I used. Now corrected.

Comment: Can you quote the number of the main theorem, as in the English translation of Marchenko, V. A.; Ostrovskii, I. V. "A characterization of the spectrum of Hill’s operator"?

Comment: @user1950: It is Theorem 1.1, p. 495-496 of the English translation, The relevant definitions are just above the statement in section 1.